# how to generate table using model classes in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i want to generate table using entity model classes? Is there anyway or is it possible?[image: these are the model classes,i want to populate (generate as table in an empty db) them into]

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of table? HTML or Database?

Comment: @Jack  i did not tried anything i just downloaded this code, code don't have database script, so i just wanted to know that, is there anyway that i could generate database table using the entity model classes.

Comment: You can use Entitframework to create db from the model.

Comment: If I answered your question, please consider choosing my answer as "Best Answer". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to generate your database on the fly if you are using Entity Framework.

From [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/) on the MSDN, in the [Adding a Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model) section:

> You'll use a .NET Framework data-access technology known as the Entity
>   Framework to define and work with these model classes. The Entity
>   Framework (often referred to as EF) supports a development paradigm
>   called Code First. Code First allows you to create model objects by
>   writing simple classes. (These are also known as POCO classes, from
>   "plain-old CLR objects.") **You can then have the database created on
>   the fly from your classes, which enables a very clean and rapid
>   development workflow.**

Essentially, EF allows you to generate the database tables from your model classes, which is what you're asking about. You'll have to setup a database connection and DbContext classes, but the articles explain in detail how to do all of that.

If you're new to ASP.NET MVC or Entity Framework, I suggest you take a look at these articles starting from the beginning. You'll have a much better understanding of how the process works afterwards, and you'll likely be able to figure out this problem yourself.